# Is it possible to use an HTTP proxy with capybara?

Tags: capybara

Capybara's API doesn't seem to support configuring an HTTP proxy. Is there any way to use one with it?

Context: I'm using capybara with cucumber to test a rails application, and akephalos as the javascript driver. There's a `script` tag on the page that makes a request to an external site (in this case, maps.google.com). The cucumber test fails with the following message:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://maps.google.com refused (NativeException)
(drbunix:///tmp/akephalos.24700.sock) -e:1
./features/step_definitions/named_element_steps.rb:20
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Akephalos, but it is certainly possible with Selenium/Firefox:

```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

    profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1 # manual proxy config
    profile["network.proxy.http"] = "http://example.com"
    profile["network.proxy.http_port"] = 80

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile)
  end
```